# MS Access or SQL Server CE for portable client application (performance basis)

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-ce, rdbms

I am using a MS Access 2007 database (`.accdb`) with password encryption in my client application, built in Visual Studio 2010 with the .NET framework 3.5. My database size is **1.0 GB** and will grow to **1.7 GB** max. There are no forms/reports (macros etc.) in the database.

There are several calculations performed in tables which leads to decrease in performance of the application. It's a client portable software and I want to increase the performance (loading data {select query}) of database. I cannot use SQL Server Express (LocalDB etc) since it does not support database encryption like `.accdb` and `.sdf` support.

I have gone though several SO posts like [SQL Server CE or MS Access for a portable database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354145/sql-server-ce-or-access-for-a-portable-database-with-c), which is targeted to Storage of DB. And [Cases where MS Access is a better choice than SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823314/are-there-any-cases-where-ms-access-is-a-better-choice-than-sql-server), which is between SQL Server and MS Access.

I am reading data from table having millions of rows (database size is about 1GB , just because of this table). Its taking too much time in reading data row by row (almost entire fields of row), i have used indexing.

- Should I go for SQL Server CE to increase performance (selecting row by row data) ? If yes, then SQL Server CE 3.5 or SQL Server CE 4.0 (database is not used for web purposes)?
- Is there any RDBMS option available except these two, which supports database encryption like `.accdb` and `.sdf`?

Comment: This is basically impossible for us to answer without knowing what your db is like. For all we know all your problems could be solved with an index.

Comment: @Jacobm001, i know db structure plays a vital role, but using same DB structure does SQLCE provide better performance(select, insert, update)  than accdb ?

Comment: That's impossible for us to determine.

Comment: You give a technical definition of "performance" and give us all the info that your definition relies on and we can answer your question. Meanwhile don't use a word in technical communication for which you do not have & give a specific technical meaning. In realistic practical engineering, tradeoffs are too complex for anything but a general meaning for "best". We can only use principles & estimates to come up with some sensible design variants then instrument & measure to compare particular designs empirically. That makes any question re "best" in a realistic sense too broad.

Comment: @philipxy i have edited the post, Performance is basically depending on select query, which reads the data row by row. Which is much faster in selecting or loading the data row by row.

Comment: Did you had a look on SQLite? it has encryption and will run on Win, Android and IOS.  if you decide port your app.